# Can't call WCF service from jQuery

Tags: wcf, jquery

Thou there a dozen posts that cover how to call WCF methods from jQuery, I can't make it work. I have simple WCF service application

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);

 }
```

This is the implementation

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

And this is the web.config of my service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWebApp.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWebApp.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="jQueryToWCF.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="TestWebApp.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="jQueryToWCF.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Now I'm trying to call this from jQuery ( from html page )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var param = "{value: 'Hello World!'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:5555/Service1.svc/GetData",
            data: param,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

But no call even makes to Service. I checked it up by Fiddler. But when I'm puting the url into browser, I can get the response. Can anybody help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling off and on with this for awhile.

The page that finally got me moving was this one: http://forums.asp.net/t/1765610.aspx/1

Meanwhile: Here is a functional project file that should work. You may need to replace the url in the javascript to be the correct port #.

http://submissiv.com/share/playground.wcf.service.zip

Comment: Also, This CodeProject article is the first example of cross-domain calls I've actually managed to get to work. When I integrate with the above project I'll post an updated file that does cross-domain with jsonp: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java

Comment: http://submissiv.com/share/playground.wcf.service_jsonp.zip -- This one works cross-domain.